# can anyone tell me how to fix this on click listener error?

Tags: java, android

[image]

show me some error. can anyone tell me how to fix this error

Comment: use the import to add appropriate class

Comment: If your not able to resolve this error on your own, I would recommend to read through some java/android tutorials

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Press Alt+Enter to import the clickListener and format your code .

Comment: there is a multiple choices option,which one i'm going to use..??

Comment: Choose the first one.

Comment: Use View.OnClickListener, the first one.

Comment: Change NumbersIntent to numbersIntent.

Answer (score 1):

Add `{` after `onClick(View view)` to correct mistake.
You should also click Alt+Enter to add a proper library to your java file.

Answer (score 0):

remove bracket which is below `startActivity()` and also change the "S" of `startActivity()` with small letter like "s" e.g. `startActivity(numberIntent)` and press Alt + Enter on `OnClickListener`.

Comment: Check the screenshot once again, the one OP posted. If you suggest to remove the below `}` what happens?. `onClick(View v)` is an auto generated  method stub. Removing the `}` bracket not a correct solution.